# Ceating two objects instead of one in Django

Tags: python, django

I want to create an object with transmitting some data from other model. And it works good, but instead of creation one object of model, I got two objects.

I create one object and try modify it, but it saves two objects, created and modified. I want to save only one object, which was modified. I am using the approach that was suggested to me: *[Django instance in model form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73842741/django-instance-in-model-form)*

#### Views

```
topic = Topic.objects.get(id=pk)
room = Room.objects.create(topic=topic)
form = RoomForm(request.POST, instance=room)
if request.method == 'POST':
    if form.is_valid():
        room = form.save(commit=False)
        room.host=request.user
        room.save()
        return redirect('home')
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't create an object yourself; let the form do this. With your approach, you create one in the [GET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) request, and one in the [POST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29) request:

```
def my_view(request, pk):
    topic = Topic.objects.get(id=pk)
    # no create
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RoomForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.topic_id = pk
            form.instance.host = request.user
            form.save()
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = RoomForm()
    # …
```

Comment: I need to transmit data from few fields of a specific topic object, not only the topic id. This problem appears from my past problem [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73842741/django-instance-in-model-form]. I am using the approach that was suggested to me

Comment: @kloskutov in the topic you linked has no line with `.create()` method. This is the part that you are creating the second object.

Comment: @kloskutov: that makes no difference. Th essential part, is *not* to create the object itself, and definitely not in the GET request. I think the linked answer actually violates the HTTP protocol: https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/a-get-request-with-side-effects.html

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem Can you advise me, how i can change the way to transmit instance in form to avoid creating an object? [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73842741/django-instance-in-model-form]

Comment: @kloskutov: why do you need that? We are here setting the `topic_id` of the instance, that is sufficient...

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem
I have a topic model that has themes fields (all topics are different), and I want a person to be able to choose a theme or few themes depending on which topic the room is created from, I do not know what to do in such a situation, to alter the models or try to transmit data to the form

Answer (score 0):

if you want to modify an object which created before just do this.
search from your model and update the field you want

Topic.objects.filter(id=pk).update(fields = something)

that it bro.
remember use if when you want to sure that the object you choose is the right one